# loop through a folder with special characters in the folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to move files from a folder into another folder. The folder has a special character in the name. I can't change that name.

Here is my script

```
set "MM=%Date:~4,2%" 
set "DD=%Date:~7,2%"
set "thisDate=%MM%%DD%"

set baseDir="T:\R ^& D files received"
set backupDir=%baseDir%\2022\%thisDate%

if not exist "%backupDir%\NUL" mkdir "%backupDir%"

for %%f in ("%baseDir%\*.pdf") do ( 
echo %%f  
move %%f "%backupDir%\%%f")
```

This is not working. I get

```
R
&
D
files
received\*.pdf
```

No file is moved.
Any idea or help is appreciated.

Comment: That is so very true. I don't use those characters myself, I even try to avoid spaces. However, sometimes you face a situation you can't avoid. Although your comment is correct, it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "thisdate=0419"

set "baseDir=U:\R & D files received"
set "backupDir=%baseDir%\2022\%thisDate%"

if not exist "%backupDir%\NUL" mkdir "%backupDir%"

for %%f in ("%baseDir%\*.pdf") do ( 
 echo "%%f"
 move "%%f" "%backupDir%\%%~nxf" >nul
)

DIR /s "%basedir%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Intriguingly. you've used the `set "var=value"` format for setting `thisdate` but not for the directory names. I've used a constant for `thisdate` as I use a `YYYYMMDD` date format.

Also, my test drive is `U:`, not `T:`.

Tips : Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, space or quotes - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

Your `for %%f` resolved to `for %%f in (""T:\R ^& D files received"\*.pdf") do (` hence the strange result.

Note that `%%f` contains the full pathname to the `.pdf` files - which includes spaces. Hence you need to "quote the sourcefile name" and use just the name and extension of that file (`%%~nxf`) concatenated onto the backupdirectoryname string with separator - all of which again contains a space and hence needs to be quoted.

`>nul` appended to suppress `1 file(s) moved` messages.

Comment: Excellent. That did it. Thank you very much for your help.